# How do I get the current child-scope of a ngRepeated element in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This seems like a simple question, but I've been googling around for a while and can't seem to find it.

In my JS I have something called `parseTags(book)` that takes a JSON comma-separated list of tags (`book.tags`) and parses it into an array:

```
$scope.parseTags = function(book){
    book.tags = book.tags.split(',');
};
```

In my HTML I have something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="book in books" ng-init="parseTags(book)">{{book.title}}</div>
```

Is there a way just to get the child scope from within the `$scope.parseTags` function? Instead of passing in `book` each time?

Something like:

```
$scope.parseTags = function($childScope){
     $childScope.tags = $childScope.tags.split(',');
}

<div ng-repeat="book in books" ng-init="parseTags()">{{book.title}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseTags` function is executed in context of the current child scope. So `parseTags` can also be written as:

```
$scope.parseTags = function() {
    this.book.tags = this.book.tags.split(',');
};
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/DUkDVOMjjj0khh5KCYo7?p=preview

Comment: Ah! I didn't think of using the `this` keyboard. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

you should only use ng-init for special cases when you need to use a property of the ng-repeat, I think you will better doing this kind of functionality in the controller. Unless there is a really specific reason you can't do that. I haven't seen your use of tags in the html, but looks like the kind of functionality a filter would do.

From angularjs docs:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

source: [angularjs docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: oh snap, really? I'm using `ngInit` a lot. Like, `ngInit="book.selected = false"` (bad example) etc. Is this bad practice?

Comment: I'm afraid so... I know in angularjs is quite difficult to separate html from js but you should try to do your functionality in the controller and only use the html for adding directives/filters/etc..